# How to convert string into aggregated quantiles?

Tags: r, aggregate, quantile, percentile

I have a dataframe that is nested by groups. I want to convert variable 'x' from its raw value to quantile position (20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% or 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

Here is an example of the data I'm using:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1, 5, 21, 24, 43, 47, 56, 59, 68, 69, 11, 15, 25, 27, 48, 49, 51, 55, 61, 67),
                 y=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"))
```

This is what I have tried:

```
df$z <- aggregate(df$x, by = list(df$y), FUN = function(x) quantile(x, probs = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1), na.rm = T))
```

In essence, I would like to create a new variable that looks like this:

```
df$z <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a grouped data.frame you can use `dplyr::ntile()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(z = ntile(x, 5))

# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   y [2]
       x y         z
   <dbl> <fct> <int>
 1     1 A         1
 2     5 A         1
 3    21 A         2
 4    24 A         2
 5    43 A         3
 6    47 A         3
 7    56 A         4
 8    59 A         4
 9    68 A         5
10    69 A         5
11    11 B         1
12    15 B         1
13    25 B         2
14    27 B         2
15    48 B         3
16    49 B         3
17    51 B         4
18    55 B         4
19    61 B         5
20    67 B         5
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Quick question, how can I extract the `z` column as a new column in the `df`?

Comment: @MarcoPastorMayo - As part of the pipe, you can do:  `... %>% pull(z)`.

Comment: Another comment. The `seq_along()` function is unnecessary for what I needed to do (it actually made it not work). `ntile()` is enough to get the string that matches the observations.

Comment: @MarcoPastorMayo - right,  I misunderstood as you mentioned position and the vector was already sorted. Will edit.

Comment: I have just realised that this answer actually gave me the quantiles for the whole vector, rather than the group quantiles.
Suppose the data was `df<-data.frame(x=c(1:100), y=c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50)`. In this case it would be more clear that the function gives the quantiles in relation to the whole rather than for the group. I'd really appreciate the solution to this, thanks!

Comment: @MarcoPastorMayo - If the data has been grouped, then the result will be by group.  If you've gotten a result for the vector as a whole, then you haven't grouped the data.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out the `dplyr` package was causing the `group_by` function to not work. Once I stopped using it the function worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cut` with `breaks` as the `quantile`

```
library(dplyr)  
df %>%
   group_by(y) %>%
   mutate(z = as.integer(cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 
       quantile(x, probs = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1), na.rm = TRUE)))))
# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   y [2]
#       x y         z
#   <dbl> <fct> <int>
# 1     1 A         1
# 2     5 A         1
# 3    21 A         2
# 4    24 A         2
# 5    43 A         3
# 6    47 A         3
# 7    56 A         4
# 8    59 A         4
# 9    68 A         5
#10    69 A         5
#11    11 B         1
#12    15 B         1
#13    25 B         2
#14    27 B         2
#15    48 B         3
#16    49 B         3
#17    51 B         4
#18    55 B         4
#19    61 B         5
#20    67 B         5
```

---

Or using `base R` with `ave`

```
with(df, ave(x, y, FUN = function(u) as.integer(cut(u, breaks = c(-Inf,
          quantile(u, probs = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1), na.rm = TRUE))))))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
```

NOTE: Answering based on the `quantile` question OP asked